# What is the name of this 7-pin round data connector?

Tags: connector, identification

What is the name of this 7-pin round data connector? It doesn't seem to be Mini Din 7.

[image: 7-pin data connector]

It's on the data cable from a Ohaus Defender 7000 scale indicator to the weighing base.

There are 7 pins, and the diameter of the inner ring is about 13 mm (1/2 inch).

Is this some proprietary Ohaus thing, or is there a chance to buy a matching (female) counterpart in general electronics stores, and what keywords to search for?

It's also not a full-size DIN, although they are about this size (13.2 mm), in my plug this circle is plastic, (not a conductive metal like in a DIN plug for shielding), and the arrangement of pins in a DIN 7-pin is very different:

[image: DIN-7]

Comment: It is a DIN, not a mini DIN.

Comment: @Indraneel although its the same size as a DIN, the pins are arranged differently, DIN 7-pin doesn't have a PIN i the middle, this one has 6 pins on a circle and 7-th pin in the middle.

Comment: there appears to be a logo inside the connector ... look for any markings

Comment: @yannn It is either a common variation of a DIN, or you will have to go look in the deep sea of military connectors where this arrangement is common, but the single polarizing lug may be uncommon or at the wrong angle.

Comment: @Indraneel also in this plug the ring is plastic, its not a metal shield like in a DIN plug.

Comment: It'll be [one of these for sure](https://www.google.com/search?q=7+pin+din+screw+connector&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908&sxsrf=ALeKk02m2wfymtJWlLjCRS1j2QJybIOEJQ:1598862080001&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik4MqygcXrAhWCtXEKHZyfCAQQ_AUoAXoECA4QAw&biw=1250&bih=726&dpr=1.25)